# Gradle: Properly build classpath from OSGI dependency's MANIFEST.MF

Tags: gradle, osgi

My gradle project ("osgiapp") has dependency on an OSGI project ("osgidep"), which has the following MANIFEST.MF entries:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Export-Package: test.lib,test.osgidep
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/lib.jar,.
Bundle-Name: osgidep
Bundle-Version: 1.0
Bundle-SymbolicName: osgidep
```

Two packages are exported here:

- test.lib package is provided by the lib/lib.jar included in the osgidep.jar
- test.osgidep package is provided by the osgidep.jar itself

Now, my build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'osgi'

repositories {
    flatDir {
         dirs "../osgidep"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile ":osgidep:"
}
```

And when I'm trying to build the code that uses both exported packages:

```
package test.osgi;

import test.lib.Lib;
import test.osgidep.OsgiDep;

public class Test
{
    Lib lib = new Lib();
    OsgiDep dep = new OsgiDep();
}
```

I get an compilation error saying that test.lib package does not exist.

How can I tell gradle to generate proper classpath based on the dependency's MANIFEST.MF entries?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that some of the types you need to compile `osgiapp` are "hidden" in the Bundle-Classpath of `osgidep`. `javac` knows nothing about Bundle-Classpath. You would need to extract the `lib.jar` somewhere so you can add it to the compile dependencies for `osgiapp`. Embedded jars like `lib.jar` are problematic if you need to use the bundle as a compile dependency.

Comment: That's right. What I'm looking for is some automated way to set up the classpath when using gradle - similar kind of magic Eclipse does with PDE.

Comment: I don't think PDE handles Bundle-Classpath either.

Comment: I faced the exact same issue, described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69448573/adding-pdebuild-jar-inside-the-org-eclipse-pde-build-bundle-to-the-compile-c
When you compile inside Eclipse (is this JDT / PDE ?) and add "org.eclipse.pde.build" then the "pdebuild.jar" referenced in "Bundle-Classpath" is considered.