# Adding "pdebuild.jar" inside the "org.eclipse.pde.build" bundle to the compile classpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, osgi, eclipse-pde

When I look at following the jar located at following coordinate on maven central:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.pde</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.pde.build</artifactId>
    <version>3.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I see a wired content. There is no `*.class` files inside.

[image: Content of the 'org.eclipse.pde.build-3.11.0.jar']

Only the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` seems to be relevant and correct.

Corresponding to the source:
https://git.eclipse.org/c/pde/eclipse.pde.build.git/tree/org.eclipse.pde.build/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

When I try to use the jar referenced by its maven central coordinates in my code, the Gradle build fails with an expected:

```
error: cannot access org.eclipse.pde.internal.build.IBuildPropertiesConstants
```

Which make sense because the class is located in `pdebuild.jar` inside the `org.eclipse.pde:org.eclipse.pde.build:3.11.0` jar.

I guess this line in the MANIFEST telling the Eclipse compiler to look at the jar inside the jar as well:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: pdebuild.jar
```

If I put the `pdebuild.jar` (manually extracted from the jar fetched on maven central) on the classpath:

[image: Content of the 'pdebuild.jar' extracted from 'org.eclipse.pde.build-3.11.0.jar']

Then I am able to compile.

---

How to make Gradle aware of this `Bundle-ClassPath` OSGi directive?

I found this related question: [Gradle: Properly build classpath from OSGI dependency's MANIFEST.MF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388371/gradle-properly-build-classpath-from-osgi-dependencys-manifest-mf)

From the answer, this doesn't seems to be possible

Comment: All that PDE build stuff is no longer maintained and really shouldn't be used for anything. Builds are done with [tag:tycho] these days.

Comment: Also note that all the code in pdebuild.jar expects to run as an Eclipse plug-in - so a fully set up OSGi environment. It isn't going to run in plain Java code.